# Транскрипция аудио (.mp3) в текст и замена названия файла на этот текст. Как и с помощью чего можно реализовать?

Tags: node.js, аудио, mp3, mount

У меня есть большое количество mp3-файлов с ни о чём не говорящими названиями. Каждый из файлов идёт не дольше 20 секунд. Мне нужна какая-нибудь программа или какой-нибудь скрипт, который прослушает каждый файл, поймёт что там говорится, переведёт это в текст и переименует этот файл в этот текст. И чтоб этот скрипт сделал это для каждого файла.

Во всех файлах речь на русском языке.

Я узнал, что расшифровка аудио в текст называется транскрибацией, но инструментов для своего дела я пока не нашёл.

Как можно это сделать?
Может есть какой-то скрипт для Sony Vegas или скрипт на Node JS?
Я пока что даже не представляю в сторону чего мне надо смотреть...
Благодарю за внимание

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/

Comment: В этом видео можно найти решение: https://youtu.be/8SQV-B83tPU